# SimpleXML array formatting with Linkedin API

Tags: wordpress, simplexml, linkedin-api

Im using the following function to import my users linkedin information via the public API.

All the data is importing properly except 'positions' which is an array.

What is the proper way to import the positions?

```
function getUserProfile()
    {
        try{
            // http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1061
            $response = $this->api->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),email-address,headline,summary,location,industry,positions)');
        }
        catch( LinkedInException $e ){
            throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an error: $e", 6 );
        }

        if( isset( $response['success'] ) && $response['success'] === TRUE ){
            $data = @ new SimpleXMLElement( $response['linkedin'] );

            if ( ! is_object( $data ) ){
                throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid data.", 6 );
            }

            $this->user->profile->identifier  = (string) $data->{'id'};
            $this->user->profile->firstName   = (string) $data->{'first-name'};
            $this->user->profile->lastName    = (string) $data->{'last-name'};
            $this->user->profile->displayName = trim( $this->user->profile->firstName . " " . $this->user->profile->lastName );
            $this->user->profile->industry    = (string) $data->{'industry'};
            $this->user->profile->location    = (string) $data->location->name;
            $this->user->profile->summary    = (string) $data->{'summary'};

            $this->user->profile->positionTitle    = (array) $data->position->title;

            $this->user->profile->email         = (string) $data->{'email-address'};
            $this->user->profile->emailVerified = (string) $data->{'email-address'};

            $this->user->profile->photoURL    = (string) $data->{'picture-url'};
            $this->user->profile->profileURL  = (string) $data->{'public-profile-url'};
            $this->user->profile->description = (string) $data->{'headline'};

            if( $data->{'phone-numbers'} && $data->{'phone-numbers'}->{'phone-number'} ){
                $this->user->profile->phone = (string) $data->{'phone-numbers'}->{'phone-number'}->{'phone-number'};
            }
            else{
                $this->user->profile->phone = null;
            }

            if( $data->{'date-of-birth'} ){
                $this->user->profile->birthDay   = (string) $data->{'date-of-birth'}->day;
                $this->user->profile->birthMonth = (string) $data->{'date-of-birth'}->month;
                $this->user->profile->birthYear  = (string) $data->{'date-of-birth'}->year;
            }

            if( (string) $data->{'picture-urls'}->{'picture-url'} ){ 
                $this->user->profile->photoURL  = (string) $data->{'picture-urls'}->{'picture-url'};
            }

            return $this->user->profile;
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception( "User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response.", 6 );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see no code in your example referencing 'positions'. Please provide a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a sample of the input and desired output.

Comment: @IMSoP — see this line '            $this->user->profile->positionTitle    = (array) $data->position->title;'

Comment: OK, what about it? If only that line is relevant, why have you pasted all the others? What is the current behaviour, and what do you want to happen instead? Where is the sample data so we can check our answers?